# Custom shape divs, is it possible i am stuck with squares

Tags: css, html, vector, z-index, transparent

Here i am again desprately asking for help..

here is the link http://panjtansoft.com/cozeez/products/fdgsd

If you look at the live image section, i am trying to get a product so a customer can change the 3 different colours of the product.. if you pick the 3 different colours you can see what i mean...

Currently it works by a png with a transparent middle showing through the div behind with the pattern in...each section has a higher z-index

But doing it this way means i have a square white outside so i can't get them any closer..

Unless anyone can sample me some code in Flash that will change the pattern of vector shapes ???

Thanks in advance

Lee

Comment: this sounds like a job for HTML5's canvas! Check http://diveintohtml5.org/canvas.html#shapes for some example code.

Comment: What do you mean by "so i can't get them any closer? Who? and Closer to what?

Comment: No i don't think that will do it mate..... It might have to be done in flash :-(

Comment: @Sam: Closer to each other i mean.... there a 3 parts to the product but because i have them in a DIV with white background with pattern in second DIV behind I can't overlay them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you're doing it now, you are stuck with squares because your masking image is a square.  However, if, instead of a square png with a hole in it and a colored background layer, you created one transparent png of each color, then you can position them over the top of each other to line up as close as you like.